# A code to show the amount of each letter in a text document in python

Tags: python

I am the biggest rookie of all rookies in python, and i want to learn how to write a code that

A) Reads and analyses a text document, and

B) Prints how many of a certain character is in the text document

For example, if the text document said 'Hello my name is Mark' it will return as

A: 2

E: 2

H: 1 etc.

To be fair, I only know how to read text files in python because I googled it no less than 3 minutes ago, so I'm working from scratch here. The only thing I have written is

```
txt = open("file.txt","r")
print(txt.count("A")) #an experimental line, it didnt work
file.close()
```

I also tried the code

```
txt = input("Enter text here: ")
print("A: ", txt.count("A"))
...
print("z: ", txt.count("z"))
```

Which would have worked if the text file didnt have speech marks in it which made the programme return only information from the things in the speech marks, hence text files.

Comment: What about reading a python tutorial first?

Comment: When you say it didn't work, can include the error or at least a string that produces the error? We don't have your text file

Comment: Agreed about reading tutorials and coming back with specific questions. You probably will need to explore [string methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_strings.htm), [I/O](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_files_io.htm), [lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_lists.htm) and [dictionaries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_dictionary.htm). But mainly, you have to define first, what your input and output is supposed to be. A text file or a user input? What happens afterwards with those numbers, do you need a dictionary or a print out?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is using `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

with open('file.txt') as fh:
    characters = collections.Counter(fh.read())

# Most common 10 characters (probably space and newlines are the first 2)
print(characters.most_common(10))
```

I'm not sure what you mean by speech marks though, we can filter out all non-alphabetical characters like this:

```
import collections
import string

allowed_characters = set(string.ascii_letters)

with open('file.txt') as fh:
    data = fh.read()
    data = (c for c in data if c in allowed_characters)
    characters = collections.Counter(data)

# Most common 10 characters
print(characters.most_common(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

txt is a file handle for your first case, it is a pointer and not container of your file.
you can try this

```
txt = open('yourfile') # read mode is the default
content = txt.read()
print (content.count('A'))
txt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example `test.txt` and the corresponding Python code to calculate each alphabet's frequency :

`test.txt` :

```
Red boxed memory, sonet. 
This is an anonymous text. 
Liverpool football club.

Two empty lines.

This is an SO (Stack Overflow) answer.
```

This is the Python code :

```
file = open('test.txt');
the_string = file.read();

alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
Alphabets = dict();
for i in alphabets:
    frequency = the_string.count(i) + the_string.count(i.capitalize());
    Alphabets[i] = frequency; 

print(Alphabets);
```

The `Alphabets` is therefore a dictionary of :
`{'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 10, 'f': 2, 'g': 0, 'h': 2, 'i': 6, 'j': 0, 'k': 1, 'l': 7, 'm': 4, 'n': 7, 'o': 13, 'p': 2, 'q': 0, 'r': 5, 's': 10, 't': 9, 'u': 2, 'v': 2, 'w': 3, 'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 0}`

You can get the frequency of an alphabet by, for example, `Alphabets['a']` which will return `6`. `Alphabets['n']` which will return `7`.

The `frequency` is including the capital letter, using `frequency = the_string.count(i) + the_string.count(i.capitalize());`.

Notice that when reading the file, each line will have an `\n` at the end, marking line spacing. This `\n` is counted as a whole, it doesn't represent a `\` char and an `n` char. So `Alphabets['n']` will not include the 'n' from `\n`.

Is this okay?